# Save JavaScript CPU Profiler data

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Simple. How do I save/export the Javascript CPU Profile data I see in Chrome Developer tools. I was debugging my site and could save the Timeline data, but didnt find an option to save Profile data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature yet. I've created a bug about that. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111198